# Submit textvalue when 5 seconds have passed

Tags: javascript, html

Im havind a small problem with my code. But problems are to be solved and i can't do it alone because i do not know were it goes wrong.

im trying to make a form with 2 textboxes, When 1 textbox is full (when there is no activity in the textbox for 5 seconds) i want it to skip to the second textbox. The same deal here but after 5 seconds without activity i want to form to submit.

This is what i have so far, i think i got all the pieces of the puzzle only no intructions to put it together.

This is what i got so far:

```
function checkfields()
            {
                var inhoudLocatieNummer = document.formsubmit.locatienummer.value;
                var inhoudbonnummer = document.formsubmit.bonnummer.value;

                document.formsubmit.locatienummer.focus();
                //delay(checkfields, contains, 500 );


                if (contains(inhoudbonnummer, "U") == true){
                    exceptionMessage("Uitbesteed werk!");
                }
                else{
                <!--geen uitbesteed werk dus kan op de normale manier verzondern worden-->
                    exceptionMessage("Normale bon!");
                }


            }

            var delayrec = {};
            function delay(callback, id, calldelay) {
                  clearTimeout(delayrec[id]);
                  delayrec[id] = setTimeout(callback, calldelay);
            }


            function contains(variable, value)  {
                if (variable.indexOf(value) >= 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function exceptionMessage(errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage);
            }
```

Can someone help me or point me into the right direction.

The problem that im having is that textbox isnt waiting for inactivity so it skips as soon as the keyup event gets triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```js
var timeoutObj;

$( ":input" ).keyup(function( event ) {

    var _this = $(this);
    
    if(_this.val().length === parseInt($(this).attr("maxlength"))){              
        
        timeoutObj = setTimeout(
            function(){ 
                _this.next('input').focus();
            }, 5000);
    }else{
        clearTimeout(timeoutObj);
    }
}).keydown(function( event ) {
    //Prevent Entrer key
    if ( event.which === 13 ) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input name="input1" id="input1" placeholder="value1"  maxlength="4"/>
    <input name="input2" id="input2" placeholder="value2"  maxlength="10"/>
    <input name="input3" id="input3" placeholder="value3" maxlength="3"/>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hg1db2sp/1/

Change the $(this).next('input').focus(); to an AJAX submit request.

Comment: I don't know why is not working in stack overflow. But in JsFiddle is working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, but i think im goeing for Reda's solution as it is more compact

Comment: His example is a "callback hell" and you have to specify the input fields. In my example works to every input in the form. Be my guest though! ;)

Comment: I will test it a little bit more but i think were on the same page after all

Comment: The problem im havind is that i do not know the lenght of user input and with this solution i cant continue to the next textbox if i do not reach the maxlenght. But like i said i do not know to max lenght

Comment: Wooohoo Thanks mate, 1 last question. How can i make it sumbit

Comment: I recommend you to use jquery as well. You can submit the form using AJAX. Take a look at this documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: The im testing the code in my project but the timer doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79651/discussion-between-the-monster-and-alysonsm).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use **jquery**, there is a functions `focus()` and `setTimeout` they are easy to use and haddle, here is a demo on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ooqq0gxt/)

Thnx !

**EDIT** Pure Javascript :

[UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/womg943k/)

Comment: Wow thats so much easier, but i need to keep it in 'vanilla' javascript because the server it will be on is as basic as it gets. Do you know a way how i can accomplish the same but then with plain javascript

Comment: Youre the best around :), 1 small issue i got. The alert that you had in de jquery, ive put it back but it triggers before de textbox gets inactive

Comment: Its work for me [link](http://jsfiddle.net/womg943k/1/) , did u start typing something in the first input ?

Comment: Yes and when it skips to the second it almost instantly submits

Comment: Yeah cause it's a small time change 1000 (1s) with 5000 (5s) !

Comment: I understand how the secons work, but i want i flawless. First of all i really want to thank you, you helped me so much. But what is happening now it that there is a timeout running in the background. Then it skips to textbox 2. But when i or an user click back in textrbox 1 it will still commit.

Comment: So what  needs to happen is that when the user is inactive for 4 seconds after filling in the textboxes then it can submit. And i think it can be accomplished with an textbox check.

Comment: Yeah Fixed Use **ClearTimeout()** function to stop counting time [UPDATE](http://jsfiddle.net/womg943k/2/)